# Как написать правильный вложенный запрос в sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Есть таблица **Школьники**, в ней поля Id , Name , SurName , Addres , Img

Есть таблица Которая содержит логин и пароль Школьников и учителей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести из таблицы Школьников Строку при условии что в Таблице SchoolAndTeachers поле логин = stydent1?

Я пробовал вот так
`Select Name From SchoolBoy Where Id = (Select * From SchoolAndTeachers Where SchoolBoy.Id = IdSchool And Login = 'student1')`

Comment: надо использовать exists()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select b.Id, b.Name, b.SurName 
From SchoolBoy b 
Where 
    EXISTS (Select 1 From SchoolAndTeachers s 
            Where s.IdSchool = b.Id And s.Login = 'student1')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [INNER JOIN (JOIN)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT
   sb.*
FROM SchoolBoy sb
    INNER JOIN SchoolAndTeachers sat ON sb.Id = sat.IdSchool
WHERE sat.Login = 'student1'
```